# Pause a loop using RStudio IDE

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to pause and continue a loop.
Does rstudio have some options that can pause a loop and continue the loop?

Just like "stop" button can stop the loop.

Comment: I suspect what's wanted is more like C's debugging, where you can send a signal and get into the debugger (On Linux/Unix, if code compiled with debug flags). I don't know a way of interrupting R code and dropping into a debugger/browser. If you just want to pause R code at the Unix shell you just hit Ctrl-Z, but that pauses the R process and gives you a Unix shell prompt back until you foreground it with 'fg'.

Comment: Not optimal but you could put a `if (file.exists("debug.txt")) {unlink("debug.txt"); browser()}` inside your loop. And create the file `debug.txt` manually when you wish to pause/debug. Type `c` [enter] to resume.

Comment: i do not want change my code, there is a red button that can stop application in rstudio, i wanna find if there is a button can pause and continue.

Comment: I heard you. The answer is no unfortunately. So all we can provide are suboptimal alternatives.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want this, but `Sys.sleep()` can be used to "pause" things for a few seconds.

Comment: perhaps, you can use `setBreakpoint` or `trace`.

Comment: What operating system? You can pause RStudio in Linux once you know its PID. You can't do anything with a paused RStudio process except start it again though. Why do you want to pause it? There's probably a way to do this in windows. Again, WHY do you want to pause it? So you can use the CPU for something else? Please answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the `readline()` function can help:

```
a <- 0

for(i in 1:4) {

    a <- a + i

    if(readline() == "0") break

}
```

Now you have to insert values for each iteration.

For instance, if you want to stop at iteration 2:

```
1
0
> a
[1] 3
```

Maybe this solution does not totally meet your requirements (I haven't really understood your question), but it may help you have a control of each iteration in order to decide if and when to stop it.

Comment: thx for your answer, but i don't want change my code, just like the red "stop" button, does studio have this button like this?